# Why do I lose what I copied with "+y after exiting vim, and how to change that?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

The + register always worked weird for me but only now I noticed a regularity in the weirdness: after I quit vim I can't paste anymore, it's as if the clipboard was replaced with a blank. Why, and can I change it to keep the copied text?

Comment: See [my answer here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19726/71)

Answer (score 0):

I usually do below and works well for me on MacOS:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

This changes the default vim register to the `+` register, which is linked to the system clipboard

Comment: It does only what you say, which isn't what I want - quitting vim still prevents me from pasting the text elsewhere

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! As the OP says, this doesn't really answer the question asked, but thanks for trying to help